# What's an example use of the "Final component of the prefix" in a systemd unit name?

Tags: systemd

Systemd allows you to create template units, as documented in [systemd.unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html).

There are a number of variables you can use in your template unit.

I'm interested in `"%j"`:

> This is the string between the last "-" and the end of the prefix name.

The "prefix name" is also defined:

> For instantiated units, this refers to the string before the first "@" character of the unit name.

I'm clear *what* they are, not clear *why* they exist.

I'm guessing perhaps they are running multiple versions of the same service. What's a real-world example of how this is used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Units can have additional settings in `.d/` directories alongside the unit. For example, `foo.service` can be extended via `foo.service.d/*.conf`.

Template units will use two directories – instance and template, so `getty@ttyS1.service` will be extended from both `getty@ttyS1.service.d/*.conf` **and** `getty@.service.d/*.conf`. This way you can extend all instances of the unit at once. In both cases, you the unit and its extension configs may use %i to get the "ttyS1" bit.

However, some units cannot use templates, e.g. slices (representing cgroups) are named `user-<UID>.slice` and not `user@<UID>.slice` because these units' name represents a *filesystem path* (the dash is mapped to a slash, and therefore "user-123.slice" is a child of "user.slice").

Because it is desired to be able to configure all individual user slices (e.g. give each slice x% of memory), a similar mechanism was added for units which use path-like names: similarly to the getty example above, the unit `user-1000.slice` can be extended from both `user-1000.slice.d/` **and** `user-.slice.d/`, with files in the latter generic directory being able to use %j to get the "1000" bit.

This last example is sort of used in practice by the default systemd installation:

```
$ systemctl cat user-1000.slice
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/user-.slice.d/10-defaults.conf
[Unit]
Description=User Slice of UID %j
```

Comment: Both answers were good, but I found this one clearer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One example of this might be systems units that refer to paths in the name. In such units, `/` is replaced by `-` (and the leading `-` is dropped). For example, a mount unit for `/home/muru` would be named `home-muru.mount`. Similarly, I can see other path-based unit names when I run `systemctl list-units`:

```
sys-devices-platform-soc-3f980000.usb-usb1-1\x2d1-1\x2d1.5-1\x2d1.5:1.0-host0-target0:0:0-0:0:0:0>
sys-devices-platform-soc-3f980000.usb-usb1-1\x2d1-1\x2d1.5-1\x2d1.5:1.0-host0-target0:0:0-0:0:0:0>
sys-devices-virtual-misc-rfkill.device          loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/virtual/misc
sys-devices-virtual-tty-ttyprintk.device        loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/virtual/tty/
sys-module-configfs.device                      loaded active plugged   /sys/module/configfs
sys-subsystem-net-devices-eth0.device           loaded active plugged   SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethern
sys-subsystem-net-devices-wlan0.device          loaded active plugged   /sys/subsystem/net/device
```

In many of these, the last component of the path, which would be the part given by `%j`, might be useful within the unit. I don't know if any of these actually use the name, but it might be convenient, for example, to use `%j` to get the username for a generator of mount units for directories in `/home`, or in `/run/user`, or similar.